# How to disable MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2Root via CMD?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I am trying to disable MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2Root via the command prompt.

```
    powershell.exe Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2Root
```

When i try to run this command, I am given the error (refer to pic):
[ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnred.png)

I am able to run this other command though (refer to pic) : [CorrectCommand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo1hx.png)

```
    powershell.exe Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2
```

Anyone able to help me with this problem? Thanks so much in advanced!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What do  you get when you run `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature  -Online  -FeatureName  MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2Root` ?

Comment: @JPBlanc No output given when i run that command

Comment: @Ray, so the feature does not exist. It explains your message.

Comment: @JPBlanc Ah okay i see thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you try :

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature  -Online  -FeatureName  MicrosoftWindowsPowerShellV2Root
```

and you receive nothing. The your error message is normal.